# Tomcat HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, spring-mvc, jetty, aether

I'm trying to make a webapp but I'm running into a problem.

First off, I've ran this webapp in Jetty and everything work perfectly. Now when I switch over to Apache tomcat 7 I'm getting errors.

The error that I receive is

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerExceptionorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:681)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)`

The root cause is

```
java.lang.NullPointerExceptionorg.eclipse.aether.examples.util.Booter.newRepositorySystemSession(Booter.java:41)
```

So I go over to that location and obviously I find out that its null.

So I'm wondering what is Tomcat doing that is making it null that jetty doesn't?

this is the fill that is returning null

```
public class ManualRepositorySystemFactory
{

public static RepositorySystem newRepositorySystem()
{
    /*
     * Aether's components implement org.eclipse.aether.spi.locator.Service to ease manual wiring and using the
     * prepopulated DefaultServiceLocator, we only need to register the repository connector factories.
     */
    DefaultServiceLocator locator = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newServiceLocator();
    locator.addService( RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, FileRepositoryConnectorFactory.class );
    locator.addService( RepositoryConnectorFactory.class, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory.class );
    locator.setServices( WagonProvider.class, new ManualWagonProvider() );

    //THis is the line that is returning a null
    return locator.getService( RepositorySystem.class ); 
}

}
```

Edit

```
public class Booter
{

public static RepositorySystem newRepositorySystem()
{
    return org.eclipse.aether.examples.manual.ManualRepositorySystemFactory.newRepositorySystem();
    // return org.eclipse.aether.examples.guice.GuiceRepositorySystemFactory.newRepositorySystem();
    // return org.eclipse.aether.examples.plexus.PlexusRepositorySystemFactory.newRepositorySystem();
}

public static DefaultRepositorySystemSession newRepositorySystemSession( RepositorySystem system )
   {
    DefaultRepositorySystemSession session = MavenRepositorySystemUtils.newSession();

   // LocalRepository localRepo = new LocalRepository( "target/local-repo" );

    LocalRepository localRepo = new LocalRepository("target/local-repo/"); // For testing purposes dls to this directory, give an option later
    ///Users/Shared/dependencyBuilder/

    session.setLocalRepositoryManager( system.newLocalRepositoryManager( session, localRepo ) ) // Line that gives me the error
```

Comment: Looks like the code you posted doesn't match the (minimal) stack trace you provided. Did you re-name something, or did you post the wrong code?

Comment: I put that code up because that is what is being called from the method. I'll edit and update the actual line thats causing the error.

Comment: So where is line 41, or what line causes the NPE? It's not easy debugging your code with very little information.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information I didn't want to overload you guys will info that might not be relavent. So right now line 41 goes to  session.setLocalRepositoryManager( system.newLocalRepositoryManager( session, localRepo ) ). The system is the null value that is giving the error. Now if you look at public class ManualRepositorySystemFactory. The line  return locator.getService( RepositorySystem.class ) is return the null. So I system.out.printed RepositorySystem.class before the error and I was actually receiving information.

Comment: So I'm unsure why locator.getService isn't able to receive any values?

Comment: I have no idea how, but it started working again. I have no clue why :(

Comment: Did you ever figure out what caused this as I'm getting the same problem?